# Django Filter Query Foreign Key

Tags: django

I'm struggling getting the right query for my project.
Here is an example or my model :

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

how do I get publisher from the book class for example I want to get all publisher for all books that have the title starting with 'hello'?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you want to get Publishers, you have to start with `Publisher`. That means you have to query through the Book → Publisher relation backwards. Here's what the docs say about it:

[Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

> To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want
>
> ...
>
> To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.

The query:

```
Publisher.objects.filter(book__title__startswith='hello')
```

Comment: What if I want to see all books published by some publisher?

Comment: @ArindamRoychowdhury: `Book.objects.filter(publisher__name='Some')`