# Django filter data of foreign key table and primary key table

Tags: django, database

I have these two models

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=50)

class Text(models.Model):
    texts=models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    upload_text=models.ForeignKey(Upload, blank=True, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

What I want is to get `texts` from `Text` when I filter `name` from `Upload`. So I want `name`, `email` and `texts` displayed.

I know this question has been asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507171/django-filter-query-foreign-key) and I am also doing the same, but getting error.

I have tried this
`data=Text.objects.filter(upload__name__icontains=query)`
But it give me an error
`Cannot resolve keyword 'upload' into field. Choices are: id, texts, upload_text, upload_text_id`

I have also tried this.

```
data=Upload.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
data1=Text.objects.filter(upload_text__in=data)
```

But I am unable to display both at the same time in jinja2 template.

```
{% for q,t in zip(query_key,query_res) %}
{{ t.texts }} {{ q.name }}    | {{q.email}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little mistake instead of `upload__name` its `upload_text__name`:

```
data=Text.objects.filter(upload_text__name__icontains=query)
```

And, your template:

```
{% for text in data %}
{{ text.texts }} {{ text.upload_text.name }}    | {{text.upload_text.email}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you make things too complicated, you can just fetch the objects with:

```
data = Upload.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).prefetch_related('text_set')
```

and in the template, you can then iterate over the data, and obtain the related `Text`s with `.text_set`:

```
{% for upload in data %}
{% for t in upload.text_set.all %}{{ t.texts }}{% endfor %} {{ upload.name }}    | {{ upload.email }}
{% enfor %}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but can I ask you how can you make bold inside code section, like your second line ``{% for t in upload.text_set.all %}{{ t.texts }}{% endfor %} {{ upload.name }}``

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane: you wrap it in a `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` block, and then you can do HTML formatting. See the [source code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63969808/edit) of the answer.