# Referring to a relationship in queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models (`Event` and `Deligate`) related by foreign keys. I have a link on the delegate’s detail page that queries if the event is paid or not. I can’t seem to get the right query set to use.

Edit: I am trying to get the `Event` object that the `Deligate` belongs to.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    about_event = models.TextField()
    paid_event = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Deligate(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='participating_ event')
    deligate_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    deligate_bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def event_check_view(request, pk):

    deli = Deligate.objects.get(pk=pk) & Deligate.objects.get(event = 'participating_ event')
    
    if deli. paid_event:
        do something…
    else
        do something else…
```

Comment: i dont understand this part `Deligate.objects.get(event = 'participating_ event')` after you get the deligate instance why not just use `deligate.event.paid_event`

Comment: that's the part i need help with, ive tried different query set, but none has worked. I am trying to query the Event model (The event that is related to the deligate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Filter Query Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507171/django-filter-query-foreign-key)

Comment: I am really confused, are you trying to get `Deligate` object that has the `event_title` = `participating_event` if so Check Stoobish's link thats the way accessing that value using `__`

Comment: @aberkb No, i am trying to get the `Event` object that the `Deligate` belongs to...

Comment: @Stoobish unfortunately it doesn't.